# how to add Asset type image list into Carousel in flutter

Tags: flutter, carousel, assets

I have list of Images in Asset type and I have already added items into it.

How can I show the Asset type image list in Carousel in flutter

```
List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
    SizedBox(
                height: 150.0,
                width: 300.0,
                child: Carousel(
                  images: images,
                ),
                )
```

Comment: Can please explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: hi,I have a image list and i need to show it in acarousel.Images in asset type.------------------"List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();"

Comment: Please send me list data

Comment: it is look like ---->>>[Instance of 'Asset',Instance of 'Asset',Instance of 'Asset']

Comment: Post your code  I will edit it.

Comment: I posted code.can you please edit it

Comment: try this let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<Asset> images = List<Asset>();
     SizedBox(
            height: 500.0,
            width: 300.0,
            child: CarouselSlider(
             items: images.map((image) => AssetThumb(
      asset: image,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
    ),
)).toList(
),)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Flutter Package: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Follow the instructions for Installation.

Import the Package
`import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';`

You can assign your List of Widgets (in your case `Image.asset()` or `AssetImage`)

```
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
  items: [ YOUR LIST HERE ],
)
```

Additional Options Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider/example

Comment: hello,can I pass Asset type list into items here?

Comment: Yes, something like this. `items: [ AssetImage('imagePath') , AssetImage('imagePath') ]`

Comment: it is look like ---->>>[Instance of 'Asset',Instance of 'Asset',Instance of 'Asset'] .......................

Comment: my list look like this.how can i pass those into carousel

Comment: You cannot like as you mentioned in the question and there is no Widget called `Carousel` by default. You have manually installed the package and do the operations as I mentioned above.